How to enumerate over all trainers in an ML.NET training pipeline?
Is it possible to get all the trainers from a specific class of trainers in an ML.NET app and iterate over them? For example, making something like this work (which doesn't).
var allTrainers = new object[]
{
    mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.SdcaNonCalibrated(),
    mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.LbfgsMaximumEntropy()
};

foreach (var trainer in allTrainers)
{
    var trainingPipeline = dataProcessPipeline
        .Append(trainer)
        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));
}

They don't seem to use a common base type that can be put into a list and assigned to Append().
